# How to retrieve OS version details and all network adapter info in macOS?

Tags: c, macos, api

I am developing a tool which supposes to collect information about a client if installed by the user. This tool will be collecting information like 
OS version, MAC addresses, IP4, registered username and computer name.

I am very new to macOS, so please help me out and give references or any relevant links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the OS version:**

On the command line:

```
$ sysctl kern.osrelease
kern.osrelease: 12.0.0
$ sysctl kern.osversion
kern.osversion: 12A269
```

Programmatically:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

char str[256];
size_t size = sizeof(str);
int ret = sysctlbyname("kern.osrelease", str, &size, NULL, 0);
```

Darwin version to OS X release:

```
16.x.x  macOS 10.12.x Sierra
15.x.x  OS X  10.11.x El Capitan
14.x.x  OS X  10.10.x Yosemite
13.x.x  OS X  10.9.x  Mavericks
12.x.x  OS X  10.8.x  Mountain Lion
11.x.x  OS X  10.7.x  Lion
10.x.x  OS X  10.6.x  Snow Leopard
 9.x.x  OS X  10.5.x  Leopard
 8.x.x  OS X  10.4.x  Tiger
 7.x.x  OS X  10.3.x  Panther
 6.x.x  OS X  10.2.x  Jaguar
 5.x    OS X  10.1.x  Puma
```

For the network adapter you could run something like:

```
networksetup -listallhardwareports
```

And parse it out